# Bluetooth LE writeValue issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

here's my problem :

I have a small [bluetooth tracker](https://pandaunited.en.alibaba.com/product/60429913721-803918591/Factory_Supply_Smart_Bluetooth_4_0_Wireless_Mini_fitness_keychain_gps_tracker.html?spm=a2700.7803228.1998738836.187.bVWMM9) : Using Core Bluetooth, I successfully connected to the device and got the services, and the characteristics. However this device has a ringer inside and I'm struggling to make it ring...

I've got this service and characteristic :

`<CBService: 0x1742737c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 1802>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1742a1e60, UUID = 2A06, properties = 0x4, value = (null), notifying = NO>`

With the property : **writeWithoutResponse**

So, I'm trying to modify the value of that characteristic from 'null' to 1 or 2 but the value never update and I don't understand why.
I used [this](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt) as documentation to know what service/characteristic does what. In this case, I tried to modify the **Alert Level** characteristic from the **Immediate Alert** service.

Here's my code :

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(nonnull CBService *)service error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Discovered service : %@", service);

    if (peripheral != _tracker) {
        return;
    }

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        NSLog(@"- %@", characteristic);

        if ([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:@"2A06"] && [service.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:@"1802"]) {

            _alertLevel = characteristic;  

            int ring = 1;
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&ring length:1];
            NSLog(@"data : %@", data);

            [self logCharacteristicProperties:_alertLevel.properties];

            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(readValue)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

            [self.tracker writeValue:data forCharacteristic:_alertLevel type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];   
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"");
}

- (void)readValue {
    [_tracker readValueForCharacteristic:_alertLevel];
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

    if (characteristic != _alertLevel) {
        return ;
    }

    NSLog(@"updated data -> '%@'", _alertLevel.value);
}
```

The ***_tracker*** variable is a reference to the connected peripheral.

The ***_alertLevel*** variable is a reference to the Alert Level characteristic.

The resulted output :

```
2017-05-08 09:56:13.914641+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
2017-05-08 09:56:15.924735+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
2017-05-08 09:56:17.934123+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
2017-05-08 09:56:19.914376+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
2017-05-08 09:56:21.984195+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
2017-05-08 09:56:23.933688+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
2017-05-08 09:56:25.913973+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
2017-05-08 09:56:28.103446+0200 AppName[1148:225988] update data -> '(null)'
```

Does anyone know why the value stays null ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Oops, Idk why the first line is not here : "Hi everyone !"

Comment: Hey Morgan, how is your Characterisitc initialized on peripheral side? If the peripheral is hosted on iOS; make sure to set the property to writable: [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:`UUID` properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate|CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

Comment: I am sorry. I just noticed you use a GATT Characteristic. Most GATT Characteristics cannot be written with an iOS peripheral from a custom app.

Comment: @Lepidopteron, what are you talking about?  Writing to GATT characteristics is exactly what Core Bluetooth is for.

Comment: Experience I made last summer with a specific one. Whatever: Can you post your Log-Output of the NSLogs?

Comment: Besides, size of an int does not always have to be the length of 1. Use instead [NSData dataWithBytes:&integer length:sizeof(integer)]; As the Characteristc just expects 0x4 I don't know, whether int would be my type of choice.

Comment: @Lepidopteron I used that tutorial : [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1)

And I get the characteristics directly from the "didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService" method and I keep the Alert Level one. I didn't know I could create them. What is it for ?
Also I have no trouble getting the battery percentage for example. The only thing not working is the writting.

Comment: Thank you. I doubt it would make a difference, but can you try to create the NSData Object with an uint instead e.g. (although I think your Log is lookin good):
    NSMutableData *d = [NSMutableData new];
    UInt8 _int = ring;
    [d appendBytes:&_int length:1];
    return d; // Reason for this, it expects an unsigned int - so we make sure to provide it from beginning: "The value of the characteristic shall be an unsigned 8 bit integer that has a fixed point exponent of 0. The Alert Level characteristic defines the level of alert, and is one of the following three values"

Comment: In addition, try to write to the characteristic not when discovering, maybe the stacks messes something up, when you are still discovering but also start writing. Instead wait till the discovery process is finished

Comment: I created a new method `- (void)makeItRing:(UInt8)level;` that I call by touching a button. But nothing changed...

Comment: The characteristic properties value is 0x04, which means it has only `CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse`, it doesn't have `CBCharacteristicPropertyRead` (0x02). So in theory, `if (_alertLevel.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyRead){//I'm allowed to read its value} else{//I'm not allowed to read its value}` And in your case you can't.

Comment: Yeah but still, the write method should work, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Morgan The write should work indeed, but you can't read the value afterwards to check if it's correct, and since there is no response, you can't also be certain with a "acknowledge" that all went good (good format, etc.).